# Python tracing, doesnt show the indexes

Tags: python, trace

Hey people i just got a quick question, for some of you it might be very simple but please help out.
lets say we got:

```
--- modulename: test, funcname: <module>
test.py(1): nums = [3, 1, 2, 10]
test.py(3): where = 0
test.py(5): for number in range(1, len(nums)):
test.py(7):   if nums[number] < nums[where]:
test.py(9):      where = number
test.py(5): for number in range(1, len(nums)):
test.py(7):   if nums[number] < nums[where]:
test.py(5): for number in range(1, len(nums)):
test.py(7):   if nums[number] < nums[where]:
test.py(5): for number in range(1, len(nums)):
test.py(11): answer = nums[where]
 --- modulename: trace, funcname: _unsettrace
trace.py(80):         sys.settrace(None)}
```

So as you can see it doesn't show me the output i need. I need to see the numbers that its putting inside of each stage looping. Is there a way to get it done?

Comment: I need to be able to see {numbers} {where} and {answer}

Comment: You need `pdb`, not `trace`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

Comment: You need to fix the indentation in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Add print statement where you want to see output.

**Version:**

```
[root@dsp-centos ~]# python -V
Python 2.7.5
[root@dsp-centos ~]#
[root@dsp-centos ~]# python -m trace --version
trace 2.0
[root@dsp-centos ~]#
```

**Code :**

```
nums = [33, 21, 4, 8]

where = 0

for number in range(1, len(nums)):
   print number
   if nums[number] < nums[where]:

        where = number
        print where

        answer = nums[where]
        print answer
```

**Output:**

```
    [root@dsp-centos ~]# python -m trace -t a.py
 --- modulename: a, funcname: <module>
a.py(3): nums = [33, 21, 4, 8]
a.py(5): where = 0
a.py(7): for number in range(1, len(nums)):
a.py(8):    print number
1
a.py(9):    if nums[number] < nums[where]:
a.py(11):         where = number
a.py(12):         print where
1
a.py(14):         answer = nums[where]
a.py(15):         print answer
21
a.py(7): for number in range(1, len(nums)):
a.py(8):    print number
2
a.py(9):    if nums[number] < nums[where]:
a.py(11):         where = number
a.py(12):         print where
2
a.py(14):         answer = nums[where]
a.py(15):         print answer
4
a.py(7): for number in range(1, len(nums)):
a.py(8):    print number
3
a.py(9):    if nums[number] < nums[where]:
a.py(7): for number in range(1, len(nums)):
 --- modulename: trace, funcname: _unsettrace
trace.py(80):         sys.settrace(None)
[root@dsp-centos ~]#
```

Comment: Can you share python version and trace version?

Comment: Also, please share your python code after adding print statement.

Comment: python is 2.7.12 and trace 2.0

Comment: 'nums = [3, 1, 2, 10]

where = 0

for numbers in range(1, len(nums)):
    print(numbers)
    if nums[index]<nums[where]:
        where = numbers
        print(where)
answer = nums[where]
print(answer)'

Comment: Code in question has 'if nums[numbers]'. But now you have 'if nums[index]'. Any reason for this  change?

Answer (score 0):

You need to format it accordingly to see what goes inside at each step

```
nums = [33, 21, 4, 8]

where = 0

for number in range(1, len(nums)):
   print number
   if nums[number] < nums[where]:
       print where
       where = number

answer = nums[where]
print answer
```

Comment: How come , here is the output displayed sh-4.3$ python main.py  1 0 2 1 3 4

Comment: i get the same output in terminal as in my question even though i've put everything as u said. I did it before myself and it didnt work, so i was hoping there is something else that can assist me

Comment: try to run like python yourFileName.py without trace,etc